# How can I exclude files from AWS Lambda function?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I've created a lambda function with CDK, and I'm getting the code using `Code.fromAsset` from `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda`. It all works fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to exclude the TypeScript files from being added, and only add the compiled JavaScript. It looks like you can pass an `excludes` parameter, but that seems to be deprecated now.

Here's what my stack currently looks like:

#### LambdaFunctionStack.ts

```
import { Rule, Schedule } from '@aws-cdk/aws-events';
import { LambdaFunction } from '@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets';
import { Function as AwsFunction, Runtime, Code } from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';
import { Stack, Construct, Duration, StackProps } from '@aws-cdk/core';

interface FunctionStackProps extends StackProps {
  functionName: string;
}

export class FunctionStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: FunctionStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    this.lambdaFunction = new AwsFunction(this, props.functionName, {
      functionName: props.functionName,
      handler: 'src/index.handler',
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      code: Code.fromAsset('./app', { exclude: ['*.ts'] }),
      memorySize: 512,
      timeout: Duration.seconds(30),
    });

    const rule: Rule = new Rule(this, 'Rule', {
      schedule: Schedule.rate(Duration.hours(2))
    });

    rule.addTarget(new LambdaFunction(this.lambdaFunction));
  }
}
```

But unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Is there a way for me to easily exclude the TypeScript files?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version do you use of aws-sdk ? 
I guess I could be related to https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7669

Comment: you could move all the files you want to add to another folder and add the new folder. I don't think it is worth it unless the lambda size actually is a problem for you. KISS is your friend

Comment: @Traycho I'm using version 1.58.0 of the cdk, and apparently that was fixed in 1.38.0 which is strange. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonny The lambda size isn't an issue, I was just trying to tidy it up as much as possible, but I do agree that it isn't worth it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the previous comments, it's not worth the effort unless you are hitting some sort of limit with the lambda function size.

Having said that, below is an example I used for uploading a single python script. It excludes everything from the `custom_resources` directory except the `create_deployment_group.py`

```
        // Custom resource to create the deployment group
        const createDeploymentGroupLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'createDeploymentGroupLambda', {
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(
                path.join(__dirname, 'custom_resources'),
                {
                    exclude: ["**", "!create_deployment_group.py"]
                }),
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            handler: 'create_deployment_group.handler',
            role: customLambdaServiceRole,
            description: "Custom resource to create deployment group",
            memorySize: 128,
            timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(60)
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I agree, the lambda is really small, so there's no reason for doing it besides trying to tidy it up. That looks great, but I'm still stumped as to why mine isn't working as they're quite similar. What version of the CDK are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.54 version. Are there any build errors?

Comment: Hmm, I'll that version a try then. Nope, seems to think everything is fine.